# No startup / boot chime; how to bring it back?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, startup

I'm one of the lucky (?) guys who managed to get a new MacBook Pro 2016 (the version that introduced the Touch Bar).

This MBP model does not have a boot chime by default.

[There are documented ways to enable it](https://www.macobserver.com/tips/quick-tip/reenable-macbook-pro-startup-chime/), specifically going to Terminal.app and typing in:

`sudo nvram BootAudio=%01`

Unfortunately for me, this fix does not work on my own machine. [Other people have noticed this as well](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7826086?start=0&tstart=0).  My guess is that it's a firmware fix or enhancement that got rid of `BootAudio` as an option.

Does anyone know a different option to re-enable the startup chime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider trying this out:

1. Launch Terminal.app and type the following command:

   `sudo nvram StartupMute=%00`
2. If prompted enter the admin password.
3. Quit the Terminal app..
4. Make sure the volume is up before you restart your Mac.
5. Restart your Mac.

You should hear a F-sharp chord sound when your Mac boots up.

If you wish to disable it, follow the same steps as above and type the following command instead:

`sudo nvram StartupMute=%01`

<sub>Tested on a 16" 2019 MacBook Pro running macOS Catalina 10.15.3</sub>

Comment: Also disables on MacBook Pro Mid 2014 running macOS Catalina Version 10.15.4. Nice work!

Comment: Worked for me too (using Catalina Version 10.15.whatever).  WOoo Hoo!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no way to bring the startup chime back (although I'm happy to be corrected).

As for the `BootAudio` command, **it never actually worked**! <sup>1, 2</sup>

However, the `AutoBoot` option is still available. In case you don't know, the `AutoBoot` command can enable/disable the MBP from booting when the lid is opened. You can use the `AutoBoot` command as follows:

- Disable auto boot: `sudo nvram AutoBoot=%00`
- Enable auto boot: `sudo nvram AutoBoot=%01`

Personally I would leave Auto Boot on, but that's a personal preference.

<sup>1</sup> - I've *never* seen it work on a single 2016 MBP since they first became available, and I've had my hands on many!

<sup>2</sup> - See [2016 MacBook Pro: Enabling the Startup Chime... does not work](https://macperformanceguide.com/blog/2016/20161118_0834-Apple2016MacBookPro-enable-startup-chime.html). Note this was published on 18 November 2016, and remember the 2016 MBPs were launched at an Apple Event on 27 October 2016. So we have users confirming the `BootAudio` command isn't working within 3 weeks of the official launch. Keep in mind the MBPs did not ship for a while after the event as well. So, when did it *ever* work?

Comment: the `StartupMute` answer by @nimesh worked for me