# Is there a way to toggle startup sounds on a 2017 MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, audio, startup

I've been a Mac user for a while, and I was really upset about the removal of the startup sounds in the new MacBooks post-2016. I was wondering if there was a way to turn the startup sound back on, or even edit the startup procedure to play a sound file. I currently am using a 2017 MacBook Pro 15-inch running macOS 10.12.6.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No startup / boot chime; how to bring it back?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/276444/no-startup-boot-chime-how-to-bring-it-back)

Answer (score 0):

From terminal, run

```
sudo nvram BootAudio=%01
```

to change it back, just change 01 to 00 run the command again.